# Comparing artifact values in CircleCI pipeline for node coverage test

Tags: javascript, circleci, test-coverage

I would like to store the result of running “npx lcov-total coverage/lcov.info” as an artifact to then compare it with the next execution of the pipeline, and if this is a lower value than the previous one it should fail.

I would like to know how to store that value and call it to the new pipeline execution.

My config.yaml:

```
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@5.0.2

commands:
  nodesetup:
    description: checkout code, restore cache, install dependencies, save cache
    steps:
      - checkout
      - node/install-packages:
         cache-path: ~/project/node_modules
         app-dir: ~/project/

jobs:
  build_and_test:
    executor: node/default
    steps:
      - nodesetup
      - run: npm run test
      - run: npm run ci-coverage
      - run: npx lcov-total coverage/lcov.info
  
workflows:
  models_pipeline:
    jobs:
      - build_and_test
```

This is the value I need to store and compare against a previous execution
[npx lcov-total coverage/lcov.info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNH0l.png)

Thanks in advance